# Uploading image using Retrofit 1.9 not working

Tags: android, image, upload, retrofit, multipart

I'm using an external API to upload a profile photo.
http://open.convio.com/api/#teamraiser_api.uploadPersonalPhoto_method.html

Here's my code:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/CRTeamraiserAPI?method=uploadPersonalPhoto")
public void uploadPersonalPhotoAsync(
        @Query("fr_id") int frId,
        @Part("graphic_upload_file") TypedFile graphic_upload_file,
        @Query("graphic_upload_upload") boolean graphic_upload_upload,
        @Query("graphic_caption") String graphic_caption,
        @Header("sso_auth_token") String token,
        Callback<UploadPersonalPhotoResponse> callback);
```

And this is how I'm using it

```
public void uploadPersonalPhotoAsync(final String cacheKey, int frID, String token, String graphic_upload_file, boolean graphic_upload_upload) {

    File imgFile = new File(graphic_upload_file);
    TypedFile tFile = new TypedFile("image/*", imgFile);

    mTeamRaiserApi.uploadPersonalPhotoAsync(frID, tFile, true, "caption", token, new Callback<UploadPersonalPhotoResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void success(UploadPersonalPhotoResponse uploadPersonalPhotoResponse, Response response) {
            uploadPersonalPhotoResponse.lastUpdatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            uploadPersonalPhotoResponse.loadedFromCache = false;
            uploadPersonalPhotoResponse.cacheKey = cacheKey;
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new UploadPersonalPhotoEvent(uploadPersonalPhotoResponse));
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new UploadPersonalPhotoEvent(null));
        }
    });
}
```

Only the caption is updated. The log shows Content-Type: multipart/form-data as required by API.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your server accepts image/*. Try using image/png or image/jpeg.

If it doesn't work use this:

```
TypedFile typedFile = new TypedFile("multipart/form-data", new File("path/to/your/file"));
```

Make sure you are not specifying the header,

```
request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

via RequestInterceptor. The request will probably fail at server side since your’re sending multipart data and not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I used the remove method from API and it's working.
http://open.convio.com/api/#teamraiser_api.removePersonalPhoto_method.html

I implemented like this:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/CRTeamraiserAPI?method=removePersonalPhoto")
public void removePersonalPhotoAsync(
        @Query("fr_id") int frId,
        @Part("BLABLABLA")String test,
        @Query("graphic_upload_delete") boolean deletePhoto1,
        @Header("sso_auth_token") String token,
        Callback<RemovePersonalPhotoResponse> callback);
```

First, I was trying without using @Multipart and was not working. So, I included the @Multipart and a random @Part parameter and bingo! Then I tried to make some changes on the upload method, changing from Query to Part, passing the image as TypedFile, as RequestBody, as encoded String, and nothing works. The caption send as @Query is updated, but the photo is not.